How to create index pattern in AWS opensearch using API?
I've configured Opensearch domain in AWS. As part of automating configurations in opensearch, I want to create a set of index patterns.
I've tried so many APIs available online, but could not succeed. Has anyone managed to create index pattern in AWS Opensearch?

prathyush could you please add more details about what was tried already and why it failed? Also what OpenSearch version is used in this context? Why is the api needed for index patterns? Normally, for me, I've set that up post creation of the cluster manually via the OpenSearch UI ( Index management > index patterns ).

In my case (I use nodejs) I write typescript script which create opensearch index, I use @opensearch-project/opensearch npm package
import { Client } from "@opensearch-project/opensearch";
import { CampaignSearchIndex } from "../src/core/domain/indices";

const openSearchClient = new Client({
  node: process.env.OPENSEARCH_DB_NODE as string,
  auth: {
    username: process.env.OPENSEARCH_DB_USERNAME as string,
    password: process.env.OPENSEARCH_DB_PASSWORD as string,
  },
});
openSearchClient.indices.create({
  index: CampaignSearchIndex.IndexName,
  body: {
    mappings: {
      ...CampaignSearchIndex.getMapping(),
    }
  },
}).then(() => process.exit);

this is example code for nodejs, you can implements functionality like this in python.

I believe this is for creating indices in opensearch. I'm looking for API to create Index patterns in aws opensearch

I've figured it out,
I used the python code provided by aws to create index patterns.
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/opensearch-index-pattern
CURL command provided in the doc did not work as it gave me 404 not found error.
Please note that if you are creating index patterns in custom domain, please pass the headers as securitytenant instead of security_tenant mentioned in doc.
